# How do I empty the Downloads Folder

Tags: browser, downloading, delete

My internal sd card is full because the downloads folder my browser saves stuff to contains a bunch of old files.

How do I empty this downloads folder in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download a file mananger -- [Astro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) is quite popular -- and delete the contents of `/mnt/sdcard/Downloads`. The path may be different if your phone has large internal storage.